# Convert bytes to ascii and back save in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm Using python 3.5

I have a couple of byte strings representing text that is encoded in various codecs so: `b'mybytesstring'` , now some are `Utf8` encoded other are `latin1` and so on. What I want to in the following order is:

- transform the bytes string into an ascii like string.
- transform the ascii like string back to a bytes string.
- decode the bytes string with correct codec.

The problem is that I have to move the bytes string into something that does not accept bytes objects so I'm looking for a solution that lets me do `bytes -> ascii -> bytes` safely.

Comment: Do you mean you have different `bytes` objects, each encoded differently? I  don't understand what you want to do `bytes --ascii--> str --???--> bytes`?

Comment: yes I have a group of `bytes` objects all have different encodings. I need to put all of them into a container that does not accept `bytes` objects only `string` objects. Then I get them out of the container and I can decode them properly with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a solution which is much easier than I thought

```
mybytes = 'ëýđþé'.encode()
str_mybytes = str(mybytes)
again_mybytes = eval(str_mybytes)
decoded = again_mybytes.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: While using `eval`  does work, it felts a little unsafe for what I wanted to do. I found an answer that avoids the eval: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775154/701403

Answer (score 4):

```
x = x.decode().encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `encode` and `decode` methods for this, and supply the desired encoding to them. It's not clear to me if you know the encoding beforehand. If you don't know it you're in trouble. You may have to guess the encoding in some way, risking garbage output.

Comment: if you don't know the encoding, you can try using [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to guess.