# Converting python string into bytes directly without eval()

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, eval

[eval()](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) seems to be dangerous to use when processing unknown strings, which is what a part of my project is doing.

For my project I have a string, called:

```
stringAsByte = "b'a'"
```

I've tried to do the following to convert that string directly (without using eval):

```
byteRepresentation = str.encode(stringAsByte)
print(byteRepresentation) # prints b"b'a'"
```

Clearly, that didn't work, so instead of doing:

```
byteRepresentation = eval(stringAsByte) # Uses eval!

print(byteRepresentation) # prints b'a'
```

Is there another way where I can get the output b'a'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, with `ast.literal_eval` which is safe since it only evaluates *literals*.

```
>>> import ast
>>> stringAsByte = "b'a'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(stringAsByte)
b'a'
```