# Is there a way to decode bytes inside a string object in Python?

Tags: python, string, byte, decode, encode

Let me be more clear.

I'm receiving a `string` in Python like this:

```
file = "b'x\\x9c\\xb4'"
```

The type of `file` is `str`. But you can see inside of that string the format of a `<class 'bytes'>`. It was the result of calling `str(file)` once `file` was already encoded. I would like to decode it but i don't know how to decode the bytes inside of a string object.

My question is: is there a way to interpret `file` as `bytes` instead of `str` without having to call something like `bytes(file, 'utf-8')` or `file.encode('utf-8')`? The problem with these method is that i would encode the already encoded bytes as i stated before.

### Why do i need that?

I'm building an API and i need to send back as a JSON value a significantly big string. Since there was plenty of space for me to compress it, i ended using `zlib`:

```
import zlib
file = BIG_STRING
file_compressed = zlib.compress(BIG_STRING.encode(utf-8)) # Since zlib expects a bytes object
send_back({"SOME_BIG_STRING": str(file_compressed)})
```

I'm sending it back as a string because i can't send it back as a bytes object, it doesn't support that. And if i try to decode it compressed before sending i ended up facing an error:

```
send_back({"SOME_BIG_STRING": file_compressed.decode('utf-8')})
-> UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 1: invalid start byte
```

And when i receive the same string later in the program, i find myself stuck on the problem described initially.

I'm lacking knowledge right now to be able to do some workaround and couldn't find an answer to this. I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could help me!

Comment: what framework do you use to build your API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, you can call `eval("b'x\\x9c\\xb4'")` and get your result `b'x\x9c\xb4'` if you don't find any other solution. But `eval` usage isn't recommended in the common case and it will be a bad practice.

Comment: ```eval`` is a very bad idea for api calls. Not that I have a better one, though.

Comment: @goalie1998 I know, therefore I wrote about it... Usually frameworks contain compression middleware or package, hope author will write his framework or will find it

Comment: Thank you! I indeed won't be using `eval` but your answer showed me a better path to look for a solution. I ended up findind [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775126/converting-python-string-into-bytes-directly-without-eval) question wich is pretty much the same as mine and he ended up using `ast.literal_eval` which only evaluate literals.

Comment: @ChristianFrança great, thank you for a tip too :)